# Smooth Surface Plotting of a discrete data file using gnuplot

Tags: random, gnuplot, surface

I have a file with three columns. All three have different values. To plot it in a 
smooth surface with a color gradient for third column what should I do? First two columns are pseudo randomly distributed. And so do the final column.

The data file looks like this:

```
 8.4295190   0.3860565   0.3706621  
-2.9886350  -0.1156874  -0.1314160  
 8.4375611   0.2617630   0.3710158  
 8.4092863   0.3195774   0.3697725  
 8.4237288   0.3930579   0.3704075  
-1.1439280  -0.7286996  -0.0919299  
-1.0866221  -0.9426172  -0.0873246  
-0.9633012  -0.8667140  -0.0774141  
-0.8225506  -0.6229306  -0.0661029  
-0.9931836  -0.6562048  -0.0798155  
-1.3138121  -0.8559578  -0.1055823  
-0.8687813  -0.7689202  -0.0698182  
 7.3637155   1.8145656   0.1891778  
 7.4434600   1.9952866   0.1912265  
 7.5885025   1.8936264   0.1949527  
 7.3067197   1.8313323   0.1877136  
 7.5324886   2.0066328   0.1935137
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `dgrid3d` to turn your points into grid data:

```
set dgrid3d 32,32
set xyplane at 0
splot 'data' with pm3d
```

This creates a grid with 32 rows and 32 columns from your data.
[image: plot with dgrid3d]
You can increase the number of grid points to get a smoother surface and you may also want to use `set pm3d interpolate 0,0`, which means that the optimal smoothing is applied to the surface.